# Aceptar una edición cuando transcriben el código de una imagen

Tags: discusión, preguntas, ediciones-sugeridas

Hace unos minutos estaba revisando en las colas de revisión las ediciones sugeridas y me encontré con una pregunta en la que el OP había publicado una imagen con el código, el usuario que editó la pregunta transcribió todo el código y lo publicó eliminando la imagen que ya no era necesaria.

En este caso rechacé la edición he hice la aclaración de que la intención del usuario era buena pero que al aceptarla el OP no aprendería a preguntar correctamente.

Mi pregunta es ¿como actuar correctamente ante este caso específico? ¿Hice lo correcto?

Comment: Yo lo hable con Camilo en el chat, y esa es mi opinion tambien, pero estaria bueno escuchar otras opiniones, sobre todo de los moderadores, para actuar todos parejitos.

Comment: En el pasado lo he visto al menos en dos ocasiones. En mi opinión, no es que algo esté correcto o incorrecto, en ambos casos existe un critero válido y evidentemente la intención es buena también. ¿Por qué considero esto? Básicamente porque el editor de la pregunta es quien invirtió tiempo y esfuerzo y ese va a ser tema de cada quien, no podemos evitar esto ya que estoy seguro que volverá a pasar, esto siempre y cuando el resultado de ese esfuerzo es algo beneficioso para la comunidad independientemente de la intención. No estuvo mal, solo que hay mejores maneras de hacer las cosas.

Comment: Como dice @Flxtr el editor hizo un trabajo al transcribir el codigo. Yo puede que la hubiera aceptado. Al aceptar una edición, el usuario que la propuso puede recibir notificaciones con *"@"*  asi qué le enviaría también un mensaje diciendole que gracias por su aportación pero es preferible que el propio autor sea el que haga esa acción.

Comment: Yo creo que habría que valorar el esfuerzo del editor... pero con ciertas condiciones. Si la pregunta tiene futuro, es decir, es una pregunta con sentido y las respuestas son enriquecedoras, entonces es preferible que la imagen desaparezca a toda costa... si el creador de la pregunta pasa del tema entonces no veo razón para impedir que un voluntario dedique su tiempo y esfuerzo en transcribir la imagen para eliminar un pegote que antes o después provocará que la pregunta sea totalmente inutil. Si, en cambio, la pregunta no tiene demasiado futuro quizás sea más conveniente votar para eliminarla

Comment: El proceso de transcribir un código mas allá que sea loable como iniciativa es un trabajo delicado, es muy fácil equivocarse, lo cual podría desvirtuar completamente la pregunta. Yo lo aceptaría en ciertas ocasiones dónde no es mucho el código transcripto.

Comment: Coincido con @PatricioMoracho y en ese caso se debería reportar como "*Claramente en conflicto con la intención del autor*".